# Adding a generator for my custom gem (Rails > 3)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, generator

I'm trying to write a Ruby gem (with Rails 3.2.13), I have created a generator to do a file copy.

Following is my generator code

```
#<mygemname>/lib/generators/mygemname/mygemname_generator.rb

require 'rails/generators'
require 'rails/generators/migration'

module Mygemname
  module Generators
    class ConfigGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      p "testing generator"
    end 
  end
end
```

then I go to the test app in my `<mygemname>/spec/dummy` (I use Rspec for testing), so from my dummy app, when I run

```
rails g I get 

Mygemname:
  mygemname:config
```

but when I run `rails g endless:config`, I get

```
Could not find generator endless:config.
```

but when I run `rails g endless`, I get the correct result. But I would like to have the command as `rails g endless:config`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try renaming the file: `/lib/generators/mygemname/config_generator.rb`

And structure `config_generator.rb` a bit differently:

```
class Mygemname
  class ConfigGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    p "testing generator"
  end 
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked with one slight change, I had to change `class Mygemname` to `module Mygemname`, :)

Comment: I know this probably seems obvious, but I was having this same problem because I changed the name of my generator's class mid development without changing the file name. Because they were similarly named, I didn't notice it until I had been troubleshooting for about half an hour...Doh!